# Proving $g(z)=z^{2z}\sin{z}$ is not an entire function

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions, entire-functions

This is one part of a three-part question. So far, I have shown $f(z)=2^{z^2}$ is entire (since it is essentially the composition of an exponential and polynomial, both of which are entire), and that $h(z)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}z^i$ is not entire (since it only converges on the open unit disc). In both of these cases, I have not had to resort to getting the equations in the form $u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ in order to apply the Cauchy-Riemann equations. For $g(z)=z^{2z}\sin{z}$ I wouldn't even know how to get it in such a form, the methods above don't work, and don't know of any alternative methods. Could someone explain why this is non-entire, or perhaps give some hints? Thanks

Comment: How do you define $z^z$? Any problems doing that on all of the complex plane?

Comment: given $\sin(z)$ is entire, $z^{2z} \sin(z)$ is meromorphic iff $z^{2z}$ is meromorphic. But $z^{2z}$ dosn't vanish and has no pole, so if it is meromorphic then it is entire and has no zero i.e. $\log (z^{2z}) = 2z \ln z$ is entire, a contradiction (since it is not even continuous)

Comment: What is the definition of $z^{2z}?$

Comment: Okay so essentially $z^{2z}=e^{2z\ln{z}}$ and we know $\ln{z}$ isn't entire?

Comment: @zhw. IMO no problem for defining a multi-valued function and asking if it is entire, for example $(z^2)^{1/2}$. So  $z^{2z} = e^{2z \log(z)}$ is multi-valued

Comment: @user1952009 That seems sloppy to me.

Comment: For $f(z) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty z^k$  you are right that it converges only for $|z| < 1$ means it is not entire, but this is true only for power series. for example $\eta(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} n^{-s}$ (a Dirichlet series) converges only for $Re(s) > 0$ and **is entire**

Answer (score 1):

The definition of exponentiation for complex numbers $a,b$ is $a^b = \exp(b \log(a))$.  The trouble is that $\log$ is a multivalued function: if $L$ is one logarithm of $a$ then $L + 2\pi i n$ is another for any integer $n$.  Unless $b$ happens to be an integer, the result will be that $a^b$ is multivalued.  When $a$ and $b$ are functions of $z$,  you typically get logarithmic branch points when $a = 0$.

EDIT: Consider $a(z)^{b(z)} = \exp(b(z) \log a(z))$, where $a$ and $b$ are analytic and non-constant near $z_0$, and $a(z_0) = 0$.

If the zero of $a(z)$ at $z_0$ has order $m$, we have $a(z) = (z-z_0)^m g(z)$ where $g(z)$ is analytic and nonzero near $z_0$.  Suppose we start at $z_1$ near $z_0$ and go in a circle counterclockwise around $z=z_0$, attempting to maintain continuity.  Note that
$$ \dfrac{d}{dz} \log a(z) = \dfrac{a'(z)}{a(z)} = \dfrac{m}{z-z_0} + \dfrac{g'(z)}{g(z)}$$
The $g'(z)/g(z)$ term is harmless, because an analytic logarithm of $g(z)$ exists in the neighbourhood of $z_0$.  But the $m/(z-z_0)$ means when we come back to the starting point $z_1$, we will have added $2 \pi m i$ to $\log a(z)$.  Correspondingly, we will have multiplied $a(z)^{b(z)}$ by $\exp(2 \pi m i b(z_1))$ (which is not $1$ because $m b(z_1)$ is not an integer for $z_1$ sufficiently close to, but not equal, $z_0$).  Thus $a(z)^{b(z)}$ is not analytic at $z_0$.

Comment: Robert, it might be worthwhile to explain the difference between $e^z$ and $e^{z\log(e)}$, with the former an analytic function and the latter a multivalued function (since $\log(e)=1+i2n\pi$).